# Expected Values, Covariance of two independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, covariance

[image]

Hello there can anyone helo me understand the question? The question noted that X and Z are independent but the equation is Y = X^2 + Z it would be a great help,
thank you!

Comment: We **define** $Y$ as the sum of two **independent** random variables: $X^2$ and $Z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $(X,Z)\overset{\rm iid}\sim\mathcal N(0,1^2)$ (independent and standard normal distributed random variables).

Then we define $Y:=X^2+Z$.

So, clearly, when you encounter "$Y$", substitute "$X^2+Z$" and make use of the given properties for those *independent and standard normal distributed* random variables.

> a) Show $\mathsf E(Y\mid X)=X^2$.

Seems obvious.

> b) Show that $\mu_Y=1$

Use the Tower property; also known as the Law of Iterated Expectation.

> c) Show that $\mathsf E(XY)=0$ and you are given a helpful hint.

Use the hint; it is truly helpful.

> d) Show that $\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y)=0$ and thus that $\mathsf {Corr}(X,Y)=0$

Just use the definition of covariance (and correlation) and the results from the prior questions.

Comment: @MathLover Hi thanks for answering the question, I have some few clarifications: for b) is the tower property stating that the usuby=E(Y) = E (E(Y|X))? we havent discussed this in class so im clarifying if this is correct. So I just have to plug in the value and get E(Y)=E(X^2)? for c) since you said that I just have to plug in the value if Y then does that mean E(XY) = E((X^2+Z)•X))?

Comment: Indeed, $\mathsf E(Y)=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))$ is the *tower property*, but you substitute $\mathsf E(Y\mid X)=X^2$ from (a).  However, yes for (c) you indeed do use $\mathsf E(XY) = \mathsf E((X^2+Z)X)$ ... then call on the linearity of expectation and the independence of $X,Z$.  @AnnieCarmeliAntonio

Comment: for b, I followed your step, I stopped at E(Y) = E (E(X^2)) Do I replace Y on the left-hand side? @GrahamKemp

Comment: @AC18 Why would you?  $\mathsf E(Y)$ is what you are trying to find.

Comment: sorry, I wrote the wrong one, what I meant was I stopped at E(Y) = E(X^2). Is there a property that im missing to solve the right hand side?

Comment: Yes.  $X$ is standard normal, so you know its mean and variance, and from these you can obtain $\mathsf E(X^2)$

Comment: okay noted does that mean since E(X^2) is also the variance and the indicated variance for (X,Z) is 1 from N(0,1) then E(X^2) = 1?

Comment: Yes, that is what it means.